# Strange Unable to play .m3u8 live streaming on my website while VLC plays the m3u8

Tags: wordpress, http, cors, m3u8

I am trying to play a .m3u8 link through hls wordpress plugin but it doesn't play. While the same links works on VLC or any IPTV player. When I check the the console it looks like this.

[Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSlrN.png)

[Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN1vf.png)

Answer (score 1):

It’s a CORS error. You must configure the CORS headers server side. If you do not control the server, then the video can not work. It works in VLC, because VLC doesn’t check for CORS. But every web browser does.

Comment: Now I am facing another strange error. Now I can play the .m3u8 files in all browser except apple devices such iPhone, iPad, mac etc. Even linux is not playing my .m3u8 files. Any fixes please?

Comment: Post a new question, and somebody can answer it.